# Does a window receive triple click events? How can I handle higher-order clicks?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Does a window receive a message about triple-clicks, like it does for double-clicks? I can't find a `WM_LBUTTONTRIPLECLICK` message that works like the [`WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645606.aspx).

I want to implement something similar to Microsoft Word, where a triple-click selects the entire paragraph. How can I detect a triple-click on my window?

Comment: Not a bad question, just very poorly phrased almost to the point where it was unreadable. Perhaps English is not your first language, but taking a bit more time when composing your question can really pay off. I edited this one and gave you a bonus +1. Hopefully some of those downvotes tacked on when the question was first posted can be reversed.

Comment: You're right, I do not speak English, thanks anyway !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is documented on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163628.aspx

The idea is to wait for a double-click and then check for a click within a certain time period after that.

> It's not just Internet Explorer, it's also Microsoft Word and
>   Outlook®, though Outlook is slightly different in that triple-click
>   selects lines instead of paragraphs. You're right, there's no
>   `WM_LBUTTONTRIPLECLICK`, but it's not hard to implement one yourself.
>   After all, what's a triple click but three clicks in rapid succession?
>   Or a double-click and single-click in rapid succession. All you have
>   to know is how quickly do the clicks have to arrive to count as a
>   triple-click? To find out, you can call the appropriately named
>   `::GetDoubleClickTime`, which returns the double-click time in
>   milliseconds. So if you get a double-click and then a single-click
>   within this many milliseconds, it counts as a triple-click.

Comment: Just a supplement, @RaymondChen has written about this as well. Check out his post [Implementing higher-order clicks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/18/243925.aspx) and the pitfalls they involve on his *awesome* blog, [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/)